# C# inheritance: implements + extends

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Is it possible to do something like that in `C#`:

```
public class MyClass implements ClassA extends ClassB 
{

}
```

I need this because: I have two classes one of which is an `Interface` which I will be implementing in my class, but I would like to also use methods from another class, that does some stuff that I would like to use in my class.

Comment: Yes you can inherit from one class and implement any number of interfaces.

Comment: What would be the difference between the use of `ClassA` as opposed to `ClassB`? You want to equally use both as base classes, right?

Comment: @ryadavilli But how do I do it? I couldn't find correct syntax to use...

Comment: public class MyClass : ClassA, IMyInterface { }

Comment: @O.R.Mapper class A is an interface, it has no implementation. I will be making implementation my MyClass, and classB is an actuall class with code which I want my class to inherit from.

Comment: @DaveHogan oh, I didn't know you could do that. That answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: @NewProger: Ah. In other words, `ClassA` and `ClassB` should actually be `InterfaceA` and `ClassA`, respectively.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you are right. I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

C# doesn't support [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). You can derive from one class and use interfaces for your other needs.

Syntax:

```
class MyClass : Foo, IFoo, IBar
{
}

interface IFoo
{
}

interface IBar
{
}

class Foo
{
}
```

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: It does... if inheriting from class, then base class must go first, then interface(s) or else compiler error. Tested it myself.

Answer (score 10):

Try this one:

```
using System;

public interface A
{
    void DoSmth();
}

public class B
{
    public void OpA() { }
    public void OpB() { }
}

public class ClassC : B, A
{
    public void DoSmth(){}
}
```

Remember, you cannot inherit from two classes at specific class level, it could be only one class and any number of interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

It should look like this:

```
public class MyClass: ClassB, InterfaceA{
}
```

ClassB is the *base class*.

InterfaceA is an *interface*.

You can only extend one base class, but you can implement many interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
    class Base
    {
    }

    interface I1
    {
    }

    interface I2
    {
    }

    class Derived : Base, I1, I2
    {
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {

        Derived d = new Derived();
    }
```